# How do I take samples from two different dataframes based on count of a common column?

Tags: r, random

I have 2 different data frames with same data structure

1. df1 with response 'Yes' (US states as Columns)
2. df2 with response 'No'  (US states as Columns)

I want to collect samples from both df and make 1 sample data frame of specified size. I want to keep the sample data-set balanced. 
For example, if I take sample from df1 and I get 50 obs from NY state then I want 50 random from df2.

here is sample dput() link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cMeKvUfjDp6HBidue3ET8QWqsC6d6oyt

I have made a function to take samples from df and shuffle them but unable to incorporate part 2

```
sample12<- function(df1,df2,size) {
  a<-df1[sample(nrow(df1),size/2,replace = T),] 
  b<-df2[sample(nrow(df2),size/2,replace = T),]
  s1<-bind_rows(a,b)
  s2<-s1[sample(1:nrow(s1)),]
  assign('s1',s2,.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample data? Just run `dput(df[1:30,])` and post the output

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cMeKvUfjDp6HBidue3ET8QWqsC6d6oyt

Comment: Why don't you just return `s2` from your function? It seems to be doing stuff correctly. Just write `return(s2)` and call your function, it should be OK.

Comment: Turns out after s1 the data is not shuffled, so s2 is there to shuffle s1 and my requirement is different from just the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get stratification by State.

First, calculate state frequencies. Then, use sample() with frequencies as probability weights.

```
sample12<- function(df1,df2,size) {

  a.freqs <- summary(factor(df1$sitecode))
  b.freqs <- summary(factor(df2$sitecode))
  a<-df1[sample(nrow(df1),size/2,replace = T, prob=a.freqs),] 
  b<-df2[sample(nrow(df2),size/2,replace = T, prob=b.freqs),]
  s1 <- rbind(a, b)
  return(s1[ sample(size), ])
}
```

Notes.

1. don't use `assign`, like: ever. Return the value.
2. I could not properly test the code, because your example data contained only Alaska ;-)

Comment: I am getting an error "Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
Called from: sample.int(x, size, replace, prob)"      I have changed the samples

Answer (score 0):

This is my version after trial and error b.t.w this method is called **Stratified Random Sampling**

***This with sample 50% from both data frames(df1 and df2) by specified size***

```
sample12<- function(df1,df2,size,variable) {
  cat( 
    paste( 
      "please enter variable in  '' ", " Enter the final size of sample " ,' ', sep = '\n \n'
    )
  )


  if(!require(splitstackshape)){
    install.packages("splitstackshape")
    library(splitstackshape)
  }
  if(!require(dplyr)){
    install.packages("dplyr")
    library(dplyr)
  }
  a<-df1[sample(nrow(df1),size/2,replace = T),]
  freq<-summary(factor(a[,variable]))
  print(freq)
  b<-data.frame(stratified(df2,group = variable,size = freq))
  s1<-bind_rows(a,b)
  s2<-s1[sample(1:nrow(s1)),]
  print(summary(factor(s2[,variable])))
  assign('s1',s2,.GlobalEnv)
}
```